# Metro/WinRT/Windows 8 Is it possible to clear the binding of an element from the code behind?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have a set of items that need to populate a set of `TextBox`'s on a page. Every time the user clicks on a different item I want to remove the old binding from the last item and set the new bindings for the current item. If I don't do this a WinRT `The object is immutable` exception is thrown.

This code works when the first item is selected but throws an exception on the next item selection.

```
titleBinding.Source = selectedItem;
TitleBox.SetBinding(TextBox.ValueProperty, _titleBinding);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try calling ClearValue.

```
TitleBox.ClearValue(TextBox.ValueProperty);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to create completely new binding objects each time a new item loaded and then call `TitleBox.SetBinding(TextBox.ValueProperty, newBindingObject);`

Apparently you can't unbind a `Binding` object after the source has been set and it has been binded to an object.

Comment: Can you SetBinding(SomeProperty, null)?

Comment: SetBinding(.., null) throws exception

Comment: This seems unnecessary.  Try AndrewS's answer below.